# How can I create a PDF with a higher dpi on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, quartz-2d

I'm creating a PDF, to be used as a mail attachment, inside my app. Which works fine, but I have no idea how to create anything but a 72dpi PDF.

I start like this

```
CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, 595, 842);
CGContextRef context = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL([NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &mediaBox, NULL);
```

Do all my Quartz drawing inside the context, all works well, but by increasing the mediabox I can only change the size of the page.
I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't find where to specify the dpi?

Comment: PDF is a vector format.  There's no such thing as "dpi", unless you're referring to embedded bitmaps.  The coordinates are floating point, so if you want something smaller than a point, just specify it that way.  Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @Nicholas I meant drawing (bitmap) images inside the PDF context, re-reading my question I realize it was all but clear in that regard, my apologies

Comment: So CGImage doesn't really have a concept of resolution either (UIImage does, but that's not going to help you with a PDF).  It should work if you just create an image with the dimensions you want, then use `CGContextDrawImage` to draw the image into the PDF context in a rect of the size you want; it'll scale the image as appropriate. (I can't test this right now which is why I'm not posting it as an answer.)

Comment: @Nicholas that's pretty much what I attempted, draw a high dpi bitmap image inside a rectangle in the page, but it looks very pixelated and low resolution... I must be missing something, I'll have another look tomorrow, thanks for the help

Comment: @Nicholas ok, I feel rather stupid now ;), apparently the (old) low res images where not being replaced on the device for some reason... doing a clean first fixed everything. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, you can blame Xcode if it makes you feel any better :-) Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode was not replacing image files on my device, so old (low res) files were still begin used, removing the app from the device completely, and doing a clean build, fixed my problems.